# c++ Include dependencies '‘class_a’ does not name a type'

Tags: c++

I am sorry for asking this question, I know there are a lot of similar questions online, but I wasn't able to solve my problem.
My files look something like this:

File `class_a.h`:

```
#ifndef CLASS_A_H
#define CLASS_A_H

#include "class_b.h"

class class_a{

    //...
    class subclass_of_a{
        
         class_b obj_b;

    }
}
```

File `class_a.cpp`:

```
#include "class_a.h"

//...

class_a::subclass_of_a(...) : obj_b(...){
    //...
}
```

File `class_b.h`:

```
#ifndef CLASS_B_H
#define CLASS_B_H

#include "class_a.h"

class class_b{

    double function(class_a::subclass_of_a const &obj_a);

}
```

This results in following error:

```
’class_a’ does not name a type
```

I hope you can help me with this problem.

Comment: In `class_a.cpp`, do you have `#include "class_a.h"` at the top?

Comment: Oh no... you have **circular includes**.  `class_a.h` insists that `class_b.h` **must** be included first.  And `class_b.h` insists that `class_a.h` **must** be included first.  Those can't both be true.

Comment: `class_a::subclass_of_a(...) : obj_b(...)` is invalid syntax.. you can't initialize `obj_b` like that from a function.

Comment: That's a bog-standard circular inclusion problem. Unfortunately you can't solve it through the normal forward declaration solution since `class_a::subclass_of_a::obj_b` is an *instance* of `class_b` instead of a reference or a pointer. You need to rethink your design and the need for the classes to be interconnected this way.

Comment: Tell me if that duplicate works for you.

Comment: @DrewDormann Thank you for pointing that out, I misses to copy that. I have now edited the post.